# Problema com container no html e css

Tags: html, css, html5

Não tenho muito conhecimento em html ou css.

Quando minimizo a tela ou mudo a resolução, o container não segue o mesmo padrão. Da seguinte forma:

**Maximizado**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Minimizado**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por que isso ocorre e qual a melhor forma de corrigir?
Desde já agradeço a atenção.

segue como está no css:

```
#containerForm{
  float: right;     
  width: 1050px;  
  background: tomato;
}
```

Coloquei esse fundo vermelho só para melhorar a visualização

Trecho html:

```
    <div id="containerForm">     
        <form action="." method="POST">            
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit">Simular</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Quando faço isso o container não fica mais alinhado, ele joga tudo para o canto direito da tela

Comment: Sim, utilizei o float porque foi o unico jeito que achei para deixar alinhado. Qual outro jeito poderia colocar? Não sei muito sobre html ou css

Comment: Esse problema está acontecendo por conta da largura absoluta, o correto é você colocar o menu lateral e essa div com larguras relativas (%). E caso eles fiquem um  abaixo do outro, corrigir com `float:left;` e `display:inline-block;`.

Comment: Obrigado! Coloquei width: 82% e caso minimize ou mude a resolução da tela o container permanece igual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Minha opinião**

**O problema**

você esta usando medidas fixas , então sempre que a tela mudar ele ainda vai ocupar a posição que foi etabelecida

**Como resolver?**

Meu conselho é usar flex-box mais medidas relativas(%)
Vai alterando o valor percentual do width até

**Codigo**

**CSS**

```
#containerForm{
  float: right;     
  width: 60%;  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background: tomato;
}
```

Se não resolver seu problema sinta-se avontade de compartilhar sua versão estática do código no `https://jsfiddle.net/` assim posso ajudar em tempo real.

Comment: Ficou ainda melhor, muito obrigado!! Estou começando a aprender isso agora.

Comment: Isso é normal, eu recomendo fortemente fazer este curso. é o melhor curso de flex-box que eu ja vi em portugues  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwXQLZ3FdTVGjLmjwfRc0Q9TA5U-PCWp4

Comment: E para melhorar ainda mais as coisas você pode ver o curso completo de design responsivo: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwXQLZ3FdTVFi6oHo_K4IYDcwCU5-f1x5

Comment: Show!!! Vou começar a ver! Muito obrigado pela dica